# Is it possible for a Facebook page to access the ID's of every user who 'likes' that page using Facebook Connect for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I am making an app in Xcode which has users register via Facebook, their ID number is then stored in our database along with their device token so that we can send them push messages.

In order to have companies use the app, we would like them to be able to send messages to all registered users who also like their Facebook page. Obviously this means accessing a potentially huge list of IDs, but tbh I'm not sure this is even possible.

Presumably it's not done in the same way as accessing a profiles friends list as they are not friends (would they be fans? likes?). I can access a users friends list easily enough, but I would be appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction as to whether the same thing is possible for business pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow access to userId's unless they specifically allow an app permission. This can be done via asking for any permission and a userId will be given.

In your other case you get around this because a user gives permission to access their friends list.

Comment: OK thanks. I've looked it up and can't see that there would be a permission for a facebook page to get the list of all users who like the page. Does this sound like it is probably correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. There is no way to get all the user Id's of people who like your page.

Comment: In addition to my last comment, I have now created a fake FB page, added the 'manage_accounts' permission and used 'me/accounts' to access the details of the page. No reference to the list of people who like it is available though, so I still think maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: There is no possible way to get all userid's of a page. The only possible way you could get some would be to run something like a contest or other promotion to win a prize and your users would give you permission to access their details upon entering. The only way to get user Id's is for an app to ask and the user to accept.

Comment: Just a further note on how I have eventually implemented this. I now check the users likes when they first log in (i.e. checking from the users end, not the pages end), and compare it against a list of page ID's belonging to our clients. The database has a table which stores the users ID and has columns for each of the clients page, which are marked as 0 or 1 depending on if they like it or not. Not the tidiest of ways, but it works :-)